# How to load the same html but with different data and with different urls using html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, url

I've built a website using no front-end framework, but html/css and javascript only. I have a page portfolio.html with two google charts. My wish is to have all urls of the format 
`www.mydomain.se/portfolio/param1=something&something&something/param2=something&something&something...` 
(or similar) display the portfolio.html page. The charts will be served with different data depending on the url from an express backend. I know how to achieve this using a frontend framework such as Vue.js but am wondering how to achieve this using only html and javascript.

So how do I make all requests to `www.mydomain.se/portfolio/param1=something&something&something/param2=something&something&something... (or similar)` 
show my portfolio.html page with different data using only html and javascript?

I have looked around and know that you can change the url after loading a page to make it look like a different page is served for multiple urls but that's not really what I want to do.

Comment: you'd most likely process this on the server

Comment: So with SSR? Is it ok to mix SSR and CSR? @JaromandaX

Comment: change the dom using request params in express routes ,render different html pages according  to the params passed in url

Comment: so do i understand correctly, you want to display different data on the website based on the url params? But the website still is the same right? If thats what you try to achieve see me answer below.

Comment: @thomas, my express back end will send different data back to the frontend depending on the url params. The website is still the same, the data is used for the google charts.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your url would be `www.mydomain.se/portfolio?param1=something`

You can do something like this ,render different templates according to query params

```
app.get('/portfolio', function(req, res) {

if(req.query.param1=="template1")
{
res.render("template1",{data:data1});
}
else if(req.query.param1=="template2")
  {
res.render("template2",{data:data2});
}
});
```

You can also use request params like this

```
app.get('/portfolio/:param1', function(req, res) {

    if(req.params.param1=="template1")
    {
    res.render("template1",{data:data1});
    }
    else if(req.params.param1=="template2")
      {
    res.render("template2",{data:data2});
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Would template1 and template2 all be my portfolio.html? If I understand this correctly, portfolio.html will be rendered server side in your example?

Comment: Yes exactly ,they will be your portfolios and they will be rendered server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab data from the params in an URL and display it on your page you could do something like this (no express, just html and JS):

```js
const getParams = () => {
  urlSuffix = document.URL.split("?")[1]; // get params (key val pairs) as string
  let keyValPairs = urlSuffix.split("&"); // split each key-value pairs

  // store params as an object
  result = {}; 
  keyValPairs.forEach(keyVal => {
    const split = keyVal.split("=");
    result[split[0]] = split[1];
  });
  return result 
}
```

then you could do all kinds of DOM manipulations based on the values you get. For example trigger an API call and display data based on that. Hope that helps.